# Question about writing and reading a 2D integer array to a text file

Tags: c, matrix, cmd

I would like to do two Things in my code

1)Write a program to write a two dimensional integer array to a text file.
and

2)Write a second program to read a two dimensional integer array from a text file. The second program should print the matrix on screen. Also to get the filename I should use command line argument.
For example on the cmd the output should be like this:

matrix.txt

8 3 3 1

13 5 31 -8

9 9 0 42

And this is the code which I have made. However only the error message "Can't open matrix.txt" comes out. What is the problem with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define ROW 3
#define COL 4
#define FILE_NAME "matrix.txt"

void input_matrix(int matrix[ROW][COL], FILE*);

int main()
{
int Multiarray[ROW][COL];
int i, j;
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen_s(&fp, FILE_NAME, "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

else
{
    input_matrix(Multiarray, fp);

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%d ", Multiarray[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
}
//This part should print out the result of my input

close(fp);
return 0;
}

void input_matrix(int matrix[ROW][COL], FILE* fp)
{
   int i, j;
   fp = fopen_s(&fp, FILE_NAME, "w");

   for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
   {
       for (j = 0; j < COL; j++)
       {
           fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);
           // I have already scanned all the element of my array
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You're opening the file for reading. You probably want to use "rw" instead of "r" in `fopen`

Comment: Emanuel P) I tried it but the debugger doesn't work.

Comment: My guess: matrix.txt is not mymatrix.txt.

Comment: Zilog80) My mistake but the output should be matrix.txt. I'll fix that

Comment: You have the same file open for reading and writing using the same file pointer.

Comment: Instead of `fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", FILE_NAME);`, let the system tell you why it can't open the file: `perror(FILE_NAME);`

Answer (score 0):

Function fopen_s returns 0 on success. As result the program fails on success.

Try:

```
int ret = fopen_s(&fp, FILE_NAME, "r");

if (ret != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this message comes out : Exception thrown at at 0x7763FEA5 (ntdll.dll) in matrixreader.exe: 0xC0000005: access violation writing location 0x00000031.

Comment: @hong try to remove fopen_s from input_matrix()